# Need to print address details Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am very new to Java script.I need to create a text area and need to print the entered text in the screen.Can anyone help me on that.
PFA the screenshot of the screen.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you just asking for the text entered on the left to be copied to the right under the "Shipping Details" heading? Have you at least created the HTML, or you asking somebody to do the whole thing from scratch?

Comment: checking terminology ... print? on a printer?

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a free code writing service  or a *"how to"* tutorial service. It is up to you to research the basics and ask questions when you have real code that isn't working as expected. See [ask]

Answer (score 0):

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input');

input.onkeyup = function(){
    document.getElementById('preview').innerHTML = input.value;
}
```

```css
div{
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="input">
</textarea>
<div id="preview">
```

Comment: There is no jQuery tag on the question. Also dumping the text into a `<div>` won't display line breaks

Comment: Yes. Although it appears what OP needs is more complex and question is poorly asked